# Populating a dictionary with upper case values of the keys already present in the dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dict variable `d` containing character-character key value pair. All these characters are in smaller case. I want to store the corresponding upper case character mapping as key value pairs too.

The dictionary consists of these entries

```
d[q]='a'
d[w]='s'
d[e]='d'
d[r]='f'
d[t]='g'
```

I want to have this also

```
d[Q]='A'
d[W]='S'
d[E]='D'
d[R]='F'
d[T]='G'
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a generator expression to update your dictionary:

```
d.update({k.upper(): v.upper() for k, v in d.iteritems()})
```

or, for Python 3:

```
d.update({k.upper(): v.upper() for k, v in d.items()})
```

or, for Python 2.6 and earlier:

```
d.update([(k.upper(), v.upper()) for k, v in d.iteritems()])
```

This loops over all key-value pairs in `d` then adds a corresponding uppercase key-value pair.

Comment: This gives this error : RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Change the first statement to `d.update(dict((k.upper(), v.upper()) for k, v in d.iteritems()))`. Importantly, as you are updating the dictionary while iterating, it changes the size and makes the iteration invalid. Just convert the entire generator to a dictionary before passing to `d.update()`. In case, the dictionary is not that big, use the second version.

Comment: @CSSS: ah, indeed, apologies. Corrected.

Comment: `d.update(((k.upper(), v.upper()) for k, v in d.items()))` seems to work as well (at least in Python 3, dunno about Python 2, but I assume it still works)

Comment: @Volatility: That doesn't work for me, actually. I also want to do some speed comparisons to check what might be faster alternatives (dict comp vs list comp for example) in Py 2.

Comment: For 2.6, a list comprehension beats out a `dict(..)` with generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to have a lot of values it may be better to create your own dictionary class that calls `.lower` on all of the items passed to **getitem** so like so:

```
class CustomDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key.lower() == key:
            return super(CustomDict, self).__getitem__(key.lower()).lower()
        else:
            return super(CustomDict, self).__getitem__(key.lower()).upper()
d = CustomDict({"a" : "q" , "s":"w" , "d":"e", "f": "r"})
print d["A"] #prints 'Q'
print d["s"] #prints 'w'
```

This makes it so you don't have to have 2 similar references to 2 similar values.